# Mute DEBUG alerts from 'import pandas' statement

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm importing pandas and it continues to throw 7 DEBUG messages. It's happening in JupyterLab and pythonanywhere. It does not appear when I comment out the pandas import

I tried to mute them using: warnings.filterwarnings("ignore"), to no avail. 
Tried "from pandas import pandas as pd" to try and avoid any further import, etc.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from yahoo_oauth import OAuth2
from datetime import date, timedelta
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import gspread
import smtplib
import time
import pandas
```

```
[2019-06-04 10:01:56,097 DEBUG] [matplotlib.__init__.wrapper] $HOME=/home/
[2019-06-04 10:01:56,104 DEBUG] [matplotlib.__init__.wrapper] matplotlib data path /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data
[2019-06-04 10:01:56,111 DEBUG] [matplotlib.__init__.rc_params_from_file] loaded rc file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
[2019-06-04 10:01:56,126 DEBUG] [matplotlib.__init__.<module>] matplotlib version 2.2.2
[2019-06-04 10:01:56,126 DEBUG] [matplotlib.__init__.<module>] interactive is False
[2019-06-04 10:01:56,127 DEBUG] [matplotlib.__init__.<module>] platform is linux2
[2019-06-04 10:01:56,127 DEBUG] [matplotlib.__init__.<module>] loaded modules: ['requests.Cookie', 'pandas._libs.numpy',
```

... goes on for 100+ lines further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
import pandas
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial for more info on the logging module.  It looks like something you are importing is setting the log level for you (or you are setting it yourself)

Comment: This got me half way there.. I'll accept your answer, but the fix was: `import logging
logging.disable(logging.DEBUG)` Probably not best practice, but it eliminated the block of DEBUG lines.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  I think the fundamental question is what module is setting the default logging level for you....  The module shouldn't do that...

Answer (score 0):

Just add `;` at the end of the lines :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup;
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials;
from yahoo_oauth import OAuth2;
from datetime import date, timedelta;
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart;
from email.mime.text import MIMEText;

import gspread;
import smtplib;
import time;
import pandas;
```

You're welcome :)

Comment: It's weird :/  It works for me in Jupyter Notebook !

Comment: I have noticed that it only appears on the first import if I'm in Jupyter.. if I re-run, it does not appear.